# Problem overlapping shapefile and raster in R?

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, vector, overlay

I want to plot a shapefile over a raster file in R but I can't make them overlap perfectly: the raster appears to be rotated of few degrees counter-clockwise. Is it a problem with the projection?

[image]

Please consider the following example:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal) 

# Download from http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/shp/ITA_adm.zip
shape_file = "ITA_adm1.shp"
# Download from http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v3-population-density/data-download
# Setting Geography: Country, Italy; Data Attributes: Grid
pop_density_file ="w001001.adf"

italy_map <- readOGR(dsn = shape_file, layer = "ITA_adm1")
italy_map_dens <- raster(pop_density_file)

colPal <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))( 500 )

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(italy_map_dens, xlim = c(6.70, 18.32), ylim = c(35.2, 47.6), axes=FALSE, box=FALSE, legend=FALSE, col=colPal)
plot(italy_map, xlim = c(6.70, 18.32), ylim = c(35.2, 47.6), border="grey", add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Not much help but just a comment: both datasets are in plain wgs84 and work perfectly fine in QGIS. +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs . I don't know much about displaying in R but your screenshot doesn't look like plain WGS84. It looks to me like there's some weird transformation going on.

Comment: I would bet that you resized the window after plotting. For some reason the vector gets skewed when you resize the plotting device. Try plotting to a difference graphic device (i.e., jpeg, pdf) and see if the problem persist.

Answer (score 6):

I could not reproduce your problem in R (similarly to jareks, in QGIS). My output map was ok, apparently.

This is data from year 2000.

[image]

This is your code (adapted) to reproduce all the three years (1990,1995,2000) of population density available on the very interesting link you provided. They seem all fine.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal) 

italy_map <- readOGR(dsn = "C:\\...\\ITA_adm", layer = "ITA_adm1")

#ds90g  population densities in 1990, unadjusted, persons per square km
pop_density_file_1990 ="C:\\...\\ita_gpwv3_pdens_wrk_25\\itadens\\itads90ag\\w001001.adf"
#ds95g  population densities in 1995, unadjusted, persons per square km
pop_density_file_1995 ="C:\\...\\ita_gpwv3_pdens_wrk_25\\itadens\\itads95ag\\w001001.adf"
#ds00g  population densities in 2000, unadjusted, persons per square km
pop_density_file_2000 ="C:\\...\\ita_gpwv3_pdens_wrk_25\\itadens\\itads00ag\\w001001.adf"

italy_map_dens_1990 <- raster(pop_density_file_1990)
italy_map_dens_1995 <- raster(pop_density_file_1995)
italy_map_dens_2000 <- raster(pop_density_file_2000)

colPal <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))( 500 )

par(mfrow=c(1,3))

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(italy_map_dens_1990, xlim = c(6.70, 18.32), ylim = c(35.2, 47.6), axes=FALSE,   box=FALSE, legend=FALSE, col=colPal)
plot(italy_map, xlim = c(6.70, 18.32), ylim = c(35.2, 47.6), border="grey", add=TRUE)

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(italy_map_dens_1995, xlim = c(6.70, 18.32), ylim = c(35.2, 47.6), axes=FALSE,  box=FALSE, legend=FALSE, col=colPal)
plot(italy_map, xlim = c(6.70, 18.32), ylim = c(35.2, 47.6), border="grey", add=TRUE)

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(italy_map_dens_2000, xlim = c(6.70, 18.32), ylim = c(35.2, 47.6), axes=FALSE, box=FALSE, legend=FALSE, col=colPal)
plot(italy_map, xlim = c(6.70, 18.32), ylim = c(35.2, 47.6), border="grey", add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Apparently there was a bug in the rgdal package. My problem was solved after I updated it to version 0.8-12.